# How to can I go from one activity to other activity view pager fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

How to can I go from one activity to another activity view pager fragment and also that fragment contain view pager which contain two fragment and i want to go 2 nd fragment. I want to go 2nd fragment

I am trying replace `fragment` but it give **No view found Exception** .

and also try To `Intent` through i send value true value to the destination Activity and try to open that 2nd fragment . but I am not able to open that .
How to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an intent to specify the desired position of your `viewpager` before changing the activity

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class)
mIntent.putExtra("pager_position",1) // 0 in case you want the first fragment
startActivity(mIntent)
```

In the B Activity, the one with `viewpager`, make sure your `viewpager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` are initialized before getting the data from the intent.

After that you simply put this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int pageIndex = extras.getInt("pager_position")
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

In second Activity set  `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`